# Easiest way to change an Primary Key from a string to a number

Tags: database, oracle, entity-framework, schema

The database I am working on was originally prototyped (by someone else) with all the primary keys (and associated foreign keys) as strings.  The keys really need to be numeric.

The database has 16 tables with minimal test data in it.  All the data has numbers in the key fields.

What is the easiest way for me to fix this?

Comment: I started to do this manually in SQL Developer and it seemed to mean deleting the link, deleting the existing primary key, creating a new primary key, renaming the existing foreign key, creating a new foreign key, copying the data, creating a new link, deleting the old foreign key.

Doing this 21 times seems it will be REALLY painful.

Comment: I am using the Entity Framework in VS2010 and tried changing the data type for one PK/FK pair in the Entity Model (edms) and then selecting "Update Database from Model".  It appeared to create the associated SQL to make the change; but it shows "not connected" and did not make the change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a SQL script to make the change on a single association then I'll modify and repeat it 20 more times.

I did the first table (MODULES.ID to MODULE_SESSIONS.MODULE_ID association) and it worked.
Here is the script I used:

```
alter table MODULE_SESSIONS drop constraint FK_MODULE_MODULE_SESSION_FK1;
alter table MODULES drop constraint MODULES_PK;
alter table MODULES rename column ID to OLD;
alter table MODULES add ID INTEGER;
update MODULES set ID = OLD;
alter table MODULES drop column OLD;
alter table MODULE_SESSIONS rename column MODULE_ID to OLD;
alter table MODULE_SESSIONS add MODULE_ID INTEGER;
update MODULE_SESSIONS set MODULE_ID = OLD;
alter table MODULES add constraint MODULE_PK primary key(ID); 
alter table MODULE_SESSIONS add constraint FK_MODULE_MODULE_SESSION_FK1 foreign key(MODULE_ID) references MODULES(ID);
alter table MODULE_SESSIONS drop column OLD;
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly what "minimal test data" means, but you could do this with SQL Developer:

1. Export the table DDL
2. Export the data as insert statements
3. Modify the DDL script generated in 1 to update your columns to NUMBER type
4. Drop and re-create the schema
5. Apply scripts from 3 then 2.

Comment: Minimal data for test in this case is 1-10 records/table
Delete and recreate sounds like the easist approach if I had more experience and/or I had a way to backup and restore the database if things went wrong; but, I don't.  So, this approach is too risky for me at this point.